# Error message: Incorrect formatting string ___, missing conversion character in '%, c'

Tags: android, xml, format

I have an error when trying to build project in Eclipse, but the value that's getting the error was the same before the error shows and the app was running normally.

Incorrect formatting string low_battery_cantchangetofree_notificacion_message; missing conversion character in '%, c' ?

this is the string in xml:

```
<string name="low_battery_cantchangetofree_notificacion_message">No puede cambiar de estado porque su nivel de batería es menor o igual a 10 \%%, conectar el cargador para aumentar su nivel de batería y poder cambiar de estado.</string>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To correctly escape a percent sign, use it two times:

```
menor o igual a 10 %%, conectar el
```

Comment: @El_Mochiq - nice, I've removed `&#37;` from the answer, then.

Answer (score 3):

Add formatted="false" to the tag
Example :

```
<string name="TEXT_1" formatted="false">I am not 100% sure </string>
```